# Pandas datetime - keep time only as dtype datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dtype

I want the time without the date in Pandas.
I want to keep the time as dtype datetime64[ns] and not as an object so that I can determine periods between times.

The closest I have gotten is as follows, but it gives back the date in a new column not the time as needed as dtype datetime.

```
df_pres_mf['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_pres_mf['time'], format ='%H:%M', errors = 'coerce')   # returns date (1900-01-01) and actual time as a dtype datetime64[ns] format

df_pres_mf['just_time'] = df_pres_mf['time'].dt.date
df_pres_mf['normalised_time'] = df_pres_mf['time'].dt.normalize()
df_pres_mf.head()
```

Returns the date as 1900-01-01 and not the time that is needed.

Edit: Data

```
               time
1900-01-01 11:16:00
1900-01-01 15:20:00
1900-01-01 09:55:00
1900-01-01 12:01:00
```

Comment: `format='%H:%M'` isn't right. Please put full format here like `format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'` and then use `df_pres_mf['time'].dt.time`

Comment: Please add some sample data to your post @db2020

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to share any of the data.

Comment: We don't want any confidential info. Create a representational sample Dataframe that resembles your data.

Comment: 1900-01-01 11:16:00, 1900-01-01 15:20:00, 1900-01-01 09:55:00, 1900-01-01 12:01:00

Comment: It would be great if you could check out the (very different) answers that @Vishnudev and I gave and let us know if either of them gets you close to what you want to do or, if neither does, clarify what the desired end result is. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your help with this.  I went with changing the dtype to timedelta which gave a '0 days 09:55:00' formatting.  As suggested by @Stryder, the difference in times might be of use later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like Vishnudev suggested but then you would have dtype: object (or even strings, after using dt.strftime), which you said you didn't want.

What you are looking for doesn't exist, but the closest thing that I can get you is converting to timedeltas. Which won't seem like a solution at first but is actually very useful.

Convert it like this:

```
# sample df
df
>>
                 time
0 2021-02-07 09:22:00
1 2021-05-10 19:45:00
2 2021-01-14 06:53:00
3 2021-05-27 13:42:00
4 2021-01-18 17:28:00

df["timed"] = df.time - df.time.dt.normalize() 
df
>>
 
                 time           timed
0 2021-02-07 09:22:00 0 days 09:22:00  # this is just the time difference
1 2021-05-10 19:45:00 0 days 19:45:00  # since midnight, which is essentially the 
2 2021-01-14 06:53:00 0 days 06:53:00  # same thing as regular time, except
3 2021-05-27 13:42:00 0 days 13:42:00  # that you can go over 24 hours
4 2021-01-18 17:28:00 0 days 17:28:00
```

this allows you to calculate periods between times like this:

```
# subtract the last time from the current
df["difference"] = df.timed - df.timed.shift() 
df
Out[48]: 
                 time           timed        difference
0 2021-02-07 09:22:00 0 days 09:22:00               NaT
1 2021-05-10 19:45:00 0 days 19:45:00   0 days 10:23:00
2 2021-01-14 06:53:00 0 days 06:53:00 -1 days +11:08:00  # <-- this is because the last
3 2021-05-27 13:42:00 0 days 13:42:00   0 days 06:49:00  # time was later than the current
4 2021-01-18 17:28:00 0 days 17:28:00   0 days 03:46:00  # (see below)
```

to get rid of odd differences, make it absolute:

```
df["abs_difference"] = df.difference.abs()
df
>>
                 time           timed        difference  abs_difference
0 2021-02-07 09:22:00 0 days 09:22:00               NaT             NaT
1 2021-05-10 19:45:00 0 days 19:45:00   0 days 10:23:00 0 days 10:23:00
2 2021-01-14 06:53:00 0 days 06:53:00 -1 days +11:08:00 0 days 12:52:00  ### <<--
3 2021-05-27 13:42:00 0 days 13:42:00   0 days 06:49:00 0 days 06:49:00
4 2021-01-18 17:28:00 0 days 17:28:00   0 days 03:46:00 0 days 03:46:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Use proper formatting according to your date format and convert to datetime

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Format according to the preferred format

```
df['time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')
```

Output

```
0    11:16
1    15:20
2    09:55
3    12:01
Name: time, dtype: object
```

Comment: Could you explain why he should go for dtype object anyway, and how dt.strftime would allow him to calculate periods between times? from the first sentence in the question: *"[...] and not as an object so that I can determine periods between times"*

Comment: What I understood is that OP wanted the time column as datetime rather than object. You could look at the comment in the first line of his code. @Stryder I think thats why there is a confusion.

Comment: I see what you mean